# Jasperserver 5.6- How to create folder using rest_v2 resources service

Tags: rest, jasperserver

I am trying to create a folder using the rest_v2 resources service. I am sending the resource descriptor xml as part of the request body in my request PUT. I am always getting a bad request error and don't know what I am doing wrong. Please advise.

Regards
VK

Answer (score 1):

To Create a folder with id "TESTREST2" in the path "/organizations/Dept/CustomReports/Reports/Sample/" ,use the below example

```
curl -X PUT http://oblclaty24advvg.odc.vzwcorp.com:8080/reportservice/rest_v2/resources/organizations/Dept/CustomReports/Reports/Sample/TESTREST2?createFolders=true -H 'Content-Type:application/repository.folder+json' -d '{   "uri" :"/organizations/Dept/CustomReports/Reports/Sample/TESTREST2", "label":"Sample test", "description":"Sample Description", "permissionMask":"1", "version":"0" }' --user user:password
```

Hope this helps!